# Difference from compiler perspective between passing by const value or const ref

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

In the context of c++.

I wonder what is the difference, between this:

```
T f(T const val);
```

and this:

```
T f(T const & val);
```

I do know one is a pass by value, but, from the compiler's pespective, this is a value that is not going to change, so my questions are:

1. Is the compiler still required to make a copy in the case of the const value parameter passing?
2. Which one is better for the optimizer of the compiler and why?

Comment: In the context of a function declaration, `T f(T const val);`, the `const` doesn't mean anything. You can ignore it (the compiler does). It only matters in the funciton definition: `T f(T const val) { /* val is const in here */}`

Comment: You might be interested in [reading copy elision rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). Basically, copy elision won't happen here.

Comment: One argument against `T f(T const val);` is that it exposes an implementation detail (the copy of `val` will not be changed inside the function) in the interface.

Comment: @ChristianHackl But it is meaningless in the *declaration*. It only serves as documentation, but the declaration is free not to use the `const` anyway. So it is double bad there.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I must have formulated my comment incorrectly, because I fully agree with you, of course. Or perhaps I misunderstand your comment? But I have the feeling that we mean the same thing., i.e. that documenting implementation details in the declaration is bad.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: As juanchopanza mentioned, it doesn't even document an implementation detail -- whether `const` is in the declaration and whether `const` is in the implementation are independent.

Comment: @newacct: I know. It's like a comment saying "arg x's copy will not be modified"; the compiler does not verify it. But even if it did, it would be  a questionable practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 1:

```
T f(T const val);
```

If the compiler can't inline (or otherwise do stuff to modify the function `f`), it must make a copy of `T` and pass it to `f`. The `const` makes no difference from the perspective of the calling code, only inside the function `f`.

Example 2:

```
T f(T const & val);
```

The compiler passes the address of `val` to the function, and thus doesn't need to make a copy.

However, using reference for small/simple types will lead to extra overhead, since the argument is passed as the address of the element, and the contents of `f` will have to make extra operations to load the address then load the actual content of `val`. So it's a matter of "how complicated is it to copy `T` and how complicated is the function `f`'s use of `val`" that determines which will be most efficient. Always, if you are trying to get better performance, measure the results!

Finally, if the compiler is able to inline the code, it may well eliminate all copies of an object (assuming constructor is known and doesn't prevent being eliminated - adding I/O to the constructor for example will prevent it from being eliminated).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Removed that bit. I keep forgetting that compilers don't do that...

Comment: Even if the compiler is able to inline the code, it will not be able to eliminate the copy in most circumstances, because the outside copy of the variable might be modified during the function execution, and if it wasn't copied then it will affect the local copy, even though it is not supposed to.

Comment: @newacct: Presumably, if the value passed in is `const`, it is because the function does not modify the value - although techically possible, it's typically frowned upon (I certainly would object to that sort of thing in a code-review). So I'm working on the basis that the function does indeed NOT modify the value passed in.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: The function takes it in locally as `const`, but that doesn't mean the original passed variable is `const`. The function might not even know that something it is modifying outside the function (or something that something it calls is modifying) is the same as the reference passed in. Therefore, the compiler can't know either, except in extremely restricted circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the following:

```
launch_service(const Configuration); // launches service in a different thread

Configuration config;

launch_service(config);
config.set("key", "value");
```

If `Configuration` is taken by reference, the service running in a separate thread might read the later added configuration setting `key`. If it's taken by value (like in the example), later changes made by other threads cannot be reflected.

Which means, taking something `const value` or `const ref` is different, and the compiler has to create a copy in the former.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> **”** Is the compiler still required to make a copy in the case of the `const` value parameter passing?

Yes, the program must behave *as if* a copy is made.

In practice an address may be passed, and the function may then itself make a copy where or if that turns out to be necessary (because of calls to other functions).

Note that a top-level `const` on a formal argument is disregarded for the function type; it only affects the implementation of the function, if it’s present in the implementation’s function head.

> **”** Which one is better for the optimizer of the compiler and why?

It depends very much on the type, on the machine code inlining, on whether that value is going to be stored somewhere to be accessible after the call, and on whether whole program optimization is used. In short, it depends. As a general rule, **measure** if you think there might be an efficiency issue.